# The People Of Trutham-And-Ly

Tags: logical-deduction, liars

Here's an interesting variation on the classical liar puzzles:

Trutham-and-Ly is a small town in the north of Logistan. It is divided into two districts, Trutham and Ly, separated by a small stream. Truthamers always tell only the truth, and Lyers only tell lies. While walking over a bridge crossing the stream, you meet the two local policemen, Bob and Bill. You know that both of them are from Trutham-and-Ly.

Bill says: "Lyers never lie."

Bob says: "Bill is from the same district as I am."

Which district is Bob from?

Comment: Are you sure Bob's statement is say-able ? It's sure that Bill is a Ly-er, I find some vague paradox about Bob's statement.

Comment: @ArbitraryKangaroo Yes, the question has a unique and completely logical answer.

Comment: I don't know, I'm very stupid, and anyhow I can't understand how Bob says that, by checking the two possibilities.

Comment: Either it's a paradox, or this needs the lateral-thinking tag.

Comment: Not really, they covered this case in logic class. You may just have thought it was trivial. (and/or I'm wrong and we'll see another clarification)

Comment: @mr23ceec: Who is "you" ? Who is "they" ?

Comment: @Arbitrary Kangaroo (you're joking, right?) "You" is the hypothetical character symbolizing the reader of these lines. "They" is the secret society that includes everyone who ever taught logic to students, but is known to no one else (and members of it will deny being in it.)
[and the lowercase you in "you're" refers to Arbitrary Kangaroo specifically] [[and "may" is shorthand for "may or may not, your choice"]]

Comment: Now that I know the answer, my opinion of this question flips from good to bad. That is a bad answer and it ruins the question.

Comment: This question is extremely underrated... can I give a bounty on a question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it this?

> All Lyers are mute and illitirate (more precisely [dysgraphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysgraphia)). Bob (and Bill) are from Trutham.

Comment: But then they would surely lie six feet underground…

Comment: The point is 'Lyers' is an empty set.

Comment: Yes, I understood the point, but I'm hoping this is not the intended answer. (In particular, I would then argue that the statement "Lyers never lie" is not restricted to _currently living_ Lyers, or to the future, i.e., past Lyers that have lied would still be part of the set.)

Comment: @mr23ceec Is that the set that *needs* to be empty?

Comment: @McFry well, the set "statements made by lyers" needs to be?

Comment: @Arkku: "Lyers never lie" is restricted to current actions by virtue of tense. It's accurate to say "Neil Armstrong does not walk on the moon" even though he once did.

Comment: @McFry Yes? I mean, if the "Truthamers" set is the empty one (and also assuming you can't live in the stream) Then Bob is lying and Bill would have to be a Truthamer, which he can't, because by initial assumption, there's no such thing.

Comment: First, just as a technicality, you specified that the set of "live Lyers" is empty as opposed to the set of "Lyers". Second, the thing that needs to be empty is not the set of Lyers (although that would be sufficient), merely the set of all Lyers' verbal statements. So it is not necessary to have all Lyers dead, it is enough if they are simply mute. This is the intended solution, so if you edit your solution I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @mr23ceec Sure about that edit?

Comment: @McFry I am now. I was thinking about how to prove that Bob was not a Lyer, but "all mute" (rather than "all silent")  actually does that.

Comment: @Ninety-Three Neil Armstrong is a person whereas "Lyers" is a category or perhaps even a concept, a more equivalent statement would be "Neil Armstrongs never walk on the moon", which IMO would not necessarily be a true statement. (Also consider: "Liars never lie" is IMO a false statement even if one cannot be point out a single living liar at the moment.)

Comment: This reminded me of a joke: "Don't believe what my husband said, he lies all the time.—But he didn't say a word...—In fact he lies even when he doesn't talk!".

Comment: If this answer was the intent of the question, then the question given is flawed.  "Lyers only tell lies" is disingenuous subterfuge; them being mute means they in fact DON'T tell lies, as they don't tell anything.  If the question had stated "Truthamers always tell only the truth, while Lyers never tell the truth", it would have been correct, and provided to the careful reader the subtle hint needed to solve.

Answer (score 5):

We know that

> Bill is a lyer since the statement he says is contradicted by the facts of the question

For Bob

if he was a lyer

> He would be from the same district as Bill but would not say so.  Thus we know he is not a lyer

if he was a Truthamers

> He would be from a different district as Bill and would say so.  Thus we know he is not a Truthamers.

So I conclude that

> McFry is a lyer

Or

> lyers sleep standing up (they don't lie down) and Bill is a Truthamers.

Comment: Excellent conclusion :)

Comment: This is a disappointing and generic answer that could equally well be applied to any other liars puzzle. It's little more than "lol I give up".

Comment: @McFry and the accepted answer and the question are also equally disappointing since Bill said "Lyers never lie" which includes any form of forming a lie (nodding, writing, pointing to pictures, etc)  even if someone is mute, illiterate with dysgraphia they likely can still communicate an answer and thus lie.  Which makes Bill's statement false.

Comment: @gtwebb The correct answer is "Bob is from Trutham and lyers have never made a single statement", not "lyers have reduced statement-making abilities". I accepted that answer because it was the closest to the intended one, I'm not particularly happy with the formulation myself.

Answer (score 3):

Well, taking the obvious

> Lyers never lie -> False -> Bill is a Lyer;
>  Bill is from the same district as me -> True -> Bob is a Lyer who spoke truth, contradiction
>  Bill is from the same district as me -> False -> Bob is a Truthamer who lied, contadiction
>  Bob speaks Paradox

This implies that something else is required.

> Easiest is that Bob is from a second town, named Paradise

Alternately

> Lyers never lie, they sleep sitting, they never fall down drunk, it's really quite marvelous. They do tell lies, but that's not necessarily what the question is asking.

This (fanciful) interpretation leads us to the following

> Lyers never lie -> True -> Bill is a Truthamer
>  Bill is from the same district as me -> True or False -> Bob can be from either Trutham or Ly without contradiction

And now to determine Bob's district

> We think to the bridge, if they were both from Trutham, or both from Ly, this seems an odd spot to converse on the job; a donut shop would be far superior. Clearly the Bridge is the point where their districts, and thus duties, overlap; and so Bob is from Ly.

Answer (score 0):

> It's a paradox. If we assume the rule "Lyers only tell lies" is true, than Bill is a Lyer. But that means Bob is in essence saying "I am a liar". Neither truth teller or liars can say that. Therefore, Bob must be from out of town or something, because he can't be from either district.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I forgot to specify that Bob and Bill are indeed both from Trutham-and-Ly.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's the correct answer. Bob's just come for a chit chat with his friend Bill, form Normal-O-Vania, a neighbourhood of Trutham and Ly :)

Answer (score 0):

Bob is ...

> talking about some other Bill, not the policeman he is with.

So Bob is from ...

> Ly, maybe. Or Trutham, maybe.  All depends on where the Bill he is actually talking about comes from.

Or, a different possibility is that

> Bill comes from Trutham-and-Ly, but lives not in either district but rather on the bridge, or perhaps in a house-boat on the stream.  He can lie if he wants, but is not required to.
>  The question asks which district Bob lives in, so assuming he in fact lives in one or the other, he would thus be lying about living in the same district as Bill.
>
>  Ergo Bob is a Lyer.